# React JS IOS Field focus sent to end of text when editing text in input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Just wondering if anyone is able to help me with a little problem that is small but annoying!

I am building a web app that allows users to create a username and add social media account names in but for that i am doing checks to ensure that there are no spaces and its all lowercase.

The issue is that on Iphone when you click in the middle of the text to alter a typo or something - once you type one character it sends you to the end of the text.

Is there a way for me to stop this from happening? See below for the code:

Component being displayed:

```
        <TextInput
          id="website"
          name="website"
          placeholder="Enter a link / website"
          type="url"
          label="link/website"
          error={linkError}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setlinkError('');
            handleChange(e);
            fieldChange(e, true, true, false);
            validateLink(e.target);
          }}
          isPublic={false}
          defaultValue={data.website}
        />
```

Validations being used:

```
const fieldChange = (e: any, lowercase = false, removeSpaces = false, removeSpecialChars = false) => {
if (e && e.target && e.target.value) {
  if (lowercase) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  }
  if (removeSpaces) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(' ', '');
  }
  if (removeSpecialChars) {
    e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '');
  }    
}
}

const validateLink = (el: any) => {
    const prefixes = ['https://', 'http://'];
    let hasPrefix = false;

    prefixes.forEach((i: any) => {
      if (el.value.startsWith(i)) {
        hasPrefix = true;
      }
    })

    if (hasPrefix) {
      setlinkError('');
    } else {
      setlinkError('Please enter a valid website link - You must include https://');
    }
  }
```

handleChange method

```
const handleChange = (e: any) => {
    const target = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [target.name]: target.files ? target.files?.[0] : target.type == 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value
    });
  };
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent that behaviour? Isn't the validation still happening anyway?

Comment: @juliomalves - Because for example when you type out your email and spell it wrong you will need to remove the whole email manually and then type it out again instead of simply being able to click on the part of the text that is at fault and fix it. Yeah the validation is still happening